# html page rendering chrome vs IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table

chrome version : 84.0.4147.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)
IE version : 11.1806.16299.0 (Update versions 11.0.185)

The html page table does not render correctly in IE.  the table headers are mis-aligned.  As the picture shows, the table headers are not aligning properly only in IE. The same page renders properly with properly aligned header rows in chrome.

[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw5n1.jpg)
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3lgH.jpg)

---------------------------------html code ---------------------------

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    a {
      text-decoration: none
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center">

        <a name="JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1"></a>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="empty-cells: show; width: 792px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white;">
          <tr valign="top" style="height:0">
            <td style="width:36px"></td>
            <td style="width:73px"></td>
            <td style="width:81px"></td>
            <td style="width:75px"></td>
            <td style="width:53px"></td>
            <td style="width:68px"></td>
            <td style="width:56px"></td>
            <td style="width:50px"></td>
            <td style="width:67px"></td>
            <td style="width:50px"></td>
            <td style="width:15px"></td>
            <td style="width:55px"></td>
            <td style="width:76px"></td>
            <td style="width:1px"></td>
            <td style="width:18px"></td>
            <td style="width:18px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:36px">
            <td colspan="16">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:40px">
            <td colspan="10">
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
              <img src="_ags_e0a2016c-7fd9-49e5-b834-78a984fddbd2.html_files/img_0_0_1" style="height: 40px" alt="" /></td>
            <td colspan="2">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:1px">
            <td colspan="16">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:20px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="13" style="text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">GENERAL GAS MAINS REPORT</span></td>
            <td colspan="2">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:1px">
            <td colspan="16">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="12">
              <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
                <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="empty-cells: show; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:0">
                      <td style="width:719px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; background-color: #99CCFF; border: 1px solid #000000; ">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; ">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="empty-cells: show; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:0">
                      <td style="width:73px"></td>
                      <td style="width:81px"></td>
                      <td style="width:75px"></td>
                      <td style="width:53px"></td>
                      <td style="width:68px"></td>
                      <td style="width:56px"></td>
                      <td style="width:50px"></td>
                      <td style="width:67px"></td>
                      <td style="width:65px"></td>
                      <td style="width:55px"></td>
                      <td style="width:76px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">GISID</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Install WO #</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Pipe Line Type</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Nominal Diameter</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Material</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Coating Type</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Bonded Indicator</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Measured Length</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Operating Area</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">Tax Code</span></td>
                      <td style="pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125; font-weight: bold;">In Service Date</span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:25px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">52084809</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Distribution</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">3</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Plastic</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">No</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">458</span></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">OH-1325-Cols Central</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM</span></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:25px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">52095298</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">6101</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Distribution</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">3</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Plastic</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">No</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">33</span></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">OH-1325-Cols Central</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1/1/1992 12:00:00 AM</span></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:25px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">52095786</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Distribution</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">3</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Plastic</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">No</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">326</span></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">OH-1325-Cols Central</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM</span></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:25px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">52367289</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">6101</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Distribution</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">3</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Plastic</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">No</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">160</span></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">OH-1325-Cols Central</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1/1/1992 12:00:00 AM</span></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:25px">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">52378596</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">6101</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Distribution</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">3</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Plastic</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">No</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">45</span></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">OH-1325-Cols Central</span></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: left;">
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1/1/1992 12:00:00 AM</span></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:307px">
            <td colspan="16">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:14px">
            <td colspan="12">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-indent: 0px; text-align: right;">
              <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1</span></td>
            <td colspan="2">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top" style="height:38px">
            <td colspan="16">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--[if IE]>
<script>
var links = document.querySelectorAll('link.jrWebFont');
setTimeout(function(){ if (links) { for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { links.item(i).href = links.item(i).href; } } }, 0);
</script>
<![endif]-->
      </td>
      <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why there is so much inline CSS code. It is not a good idea to generate the nested table using complicated inline CSS code.

I noticed that for the table headers you have created another table within a table.

In that table below code is causing the issue.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; ">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="empty-cells: show; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:0">
                      <td style="width:73px"></td>
                      <td style="width:81px"></td>
                      <td style="width:75px"></td>
                      <td style="width:53px"></td>
                      <td style="width:68px"></td>
                      <td style="width:56px"></td>
                      <td style="width:50px"></td>
                      <td style="width:67px"></td>
                      <td style="width:65px"></td>
                      <td style="width:55px"></td>
                      <td style="width:76px"></td>
                    </tr>
```

You have set the width for each td tag that is causing the issue in the IE browser.

If you modify the value of the width then you can notice that headers side borders will move.

Below are some helpful points that may help you to fix the issue.

1. Try to write all the CSS code in the style tag or write it in a separate CSS file.
2. I think you do not need to create nested tables. Try to use DIVs and if you want to use the table then try to use TH tag for creating the headers.
3. I am not sure whether the table you had posted above is generated dynamically. but if you have created it manually then I think you have chosen a very complex way. Try to develop a proper CSS that can work on cross-browser and make sure that the CSS properties you are using in your code are well supported in target browsers. You can refer to the official docs to know about the browser support of any specific CSS property.